# Restriction of bijection is bijection

Tags: functions, solution-verification

I have proven the following property of bijective functions. Could you verify the argumentation and suggest improvements if you have any?

**Lemma.** Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a bijection and $C \subseteq A$. Then the restriction $ f\mid_C : C\rightarrow f(C) $ is also bijection.

**Proof.**
By assumption, $f$ is bijection, i.e.

1. $ \forall a, b\in A: \ a\ne b \Rightarrow f(a)\ne f(b) $, and
2. $ \forall c \in B: \exists x\in A: f(x)=c. $

To show that $f\mid_C $ is bijective, we need to show that

3. $ \forall a, b\in C: \ a\ne b \Rightarrow f(a)\ne f(b) $, and
4. $ \forall c \in f(C): \exists x\in C: f(x)=c. $

Let $a, b\in C\subseteq A $ so that $a\ne b $. Since $a, b \in A$ and $a \ne b$, by 1) we have $f(a)\ne f(b) $. This shows 3).

Let $ c\in f(C) $.
$$f(C) = \left\{d\in
B \mid \exists x\in C: f(x)=d \right\} $$
By the definition of $f(C)$, there exists $x' \in C$ such that $f(x')=c$. This shows 4).

Therefore $f\mid_C : C \rightarrow f(C)$ is bijective.
$\square$

As a corollary we get that $ \left|C\right|=\left| f(C)\right|. $

Comment: This looks great!

Answer (score 3):

The proof is correct. Alternatively, we may define $g:f(C) \to C$ such that $g(f(c)) := c$. This is well defined due to bijectivity of $f$. Therefore, $g \circ f\vert _C = \mathrm{id}_C$ and $f\vert _C \circ g = \mathrm{id}_{f(C)}$.

---

Aesthetically, it is prettier to work with equalities when it comes to injectivity. That is unless there is some ordering present.